# how to move directories within a directory from a shell script?

Tags: bash

trying a script to move folders from my internal to external hard disk from within a directory....

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
    if [[ $i == [* ]]; then
        mv $i /entertainment/movies/;
    fi
done
```

i get the below error:

```
mv: cannot stat 'DVDRip': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '-': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'x264': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '-': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'DD5.1': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '-': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '1GB': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '-': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'ESub': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Add quotes around `$i`:  `"$i"`

Comment: it did the trick...the 'mv' is executing...should have added the verbose to confirm it a little faster....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround variable expansions with double quotes to ensure whitespace is handled properly.

```
mv "$i" /entertainment/movies/
```

The `if` test can be omitted if you only loop over files you're interested in.

```
for i in [*; do
    mv $i /entertainment/movies/
done
```

And then you can even ditch the loop.

```
mv [* /entertainment/movies/
```